# Selenium Test with TestNG: The IntelliJ cannot recognize the 'xml' File

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, intellij-14

I am using an **IntelliJ ULTIMATE 14** in a MAC and I would like to develop a Selenium Test with TestNG. My Java class runs well. But when I create the `test.xml` file, IntelliJ does not recognize this. This means, when I click with right Button on the `test.xml` file I have not the Option to RUN the Test with the `test.xml` file.

I've been in Run/Debug Configurations and I've set up a new RUN Option:

1. `+` TestNG
2. Name: LoginTest
3. Suite Option selected
4. Suite: `/PATH/PROJECT/src/test/resources/test.xml`
5. In single Module: `/PATH/PROJECT/src/test/resources/test.xml`
6. JDK Settings / VM option: `-ea`

Below this window I get the following ERROR message:

```
Run Configuration Error: Unable to parse
`/PATH/PROJECT/src/test/resources/test.xml`
```

I have used too the Maven Dependency:

`<dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.8</version>
</dependency>`

Please someone has a tip?

**UPDATE-01:**

when I run though XML file I get the following message:

`org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 24; System-ID muss mit einem einzelnen oder doppelten Anführungszeichen beginnen.`

`at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:340)`

`at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)`

`at ...`

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 24; System-ID muss mit einem einzelnen oder doppelten Anführungszeichen beginnen.`

`at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)`

`at ...`

`Process finished with exit code 0`

**UPDATE-02**

The `test.xml` content is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

> ```
> <suite name="Login Tests">
>
> <test name="P1 Test">
>     <groups>
>         <run>
>             <include name="p1" />
>         </run>
>     </groups>
>     <classes>
>         <class name="com.facebook.tests.Login_Test"/>
>     </classes>
> </test>
>
> <test name="P2 Test">
>     <groups>
>         <run>
>             <include name="p2" />
>         </run>
>     </groups>
>     <classes>
>         <class name="com.facebook.tests.Login_Test">
>             <methods>
>                 <exclude name="filloutPassFld"/>
>             </methods>
>         </class>
>     </classes>
> </test>
>
>
> </suite>
> ```

Comment: What error you getting when run though XML?

Comment: Hi Helping Hands, please see my UPDATE-01. Thanks.

Comment: Why you are using plugin IntelliJ? Any special purpose?

Comment: I would like run a Parallel Test with the Code in file from the **UPDATE-02** above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the test.xml content. Obviously, SAXParser complains about it:
System ID must begin with a single or double quotes.

Comment: Hi Johnny C, please see my **UPDATE-02**. IntelliJ cannot recognize it. It will be a problem with puglins?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
First line of the xml ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In `test.xml` file I forgot the quotes ("") in the command:

**DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"**

Thanks for listening.